# Ipconfig /all using C programming leads to incomplete command line error

Tags: c

A programming beginner here so I am working on a simple program that uses the user's input to name a text file and then the program stores the ipconfig /all information in that text file. I receive an error "unrecognized or incomplete command line." I understand it's quite easy to write the ipconfig /all to a text file using the command prompt but I was hoping to get it working using C.

Thank you!

```
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LEN 20

int main()
{
    char myfile[MAX_LEN];

    printf ("Enter text file name: ");
    scanf ("%s", myfile);

    system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ipconfig /all 2>&1 \\Location\myfile.txt");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're forgetting 1) to use your `myfile` variable (you have to format your command) 2) a `>` just before the file. But don't do this, use `popen`

Comment: You escape all backslashes *except one* (or possibly three, depending on what `Location` is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a lot of errors here

- not using the string you just inputted
- wrong escaping of backslashes
- forgetting a redirection in the command line (just before the filename). Ex: `system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ipconfig /all 2>&1 > myfile.txt")`

but:

- you shouldn't use `system` for this, `popen` can get a command output, no need for ugly redirections
- no need to silence standard error, all the interesting output is in standard output
- no need to specify the path for the command it's a system command already in the path

my proposal using `popen` (which is missing some error checking and whatnot, but basically works) which returns you a pipe handle. Just read it char by char until the end and write the result in an output file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX_LEN 20

int main()
{
    char myfile[MAX_LEN];

    printf ("Enter text file name: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf ("%19s", myfile);
    FILE *f = popen("ipconfig /all","r");
    FILE *fw = fopen(myfile,"w");
    if (fw)
    {
     while(1)
     {
       int c = fgetc(f);
       if (c == EOF) break;
       fputc(c,fw);
     }
     fclose(fw);
     pclose(f);
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll be working on familiarizing myself with this code. Thank you for the thorough explanation.